# Create category after theme setup and modify the default one

Tags: php, categories, theme-development, terms

I need to modify the default category that is created by wordpress after the installation. I want to create a new one and modify the existing one after that my theme is activated. Is this possible?

Comment: yes, what have you got so far?

Comment: @RiddleMeThis nothing because I don't know if there is an hook or similar to achieve this, this is why I'm asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [wp_update_term](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_term/) to modify terms (even the default uncategorized) and [wp_insert_term](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_term/) to update existing terms.

Here is a basic example that should get you there.

```
function add_category(){

    // Update Uncategorized Category (1)
    wp_update_term(
        1, 
        'category',
        array(
          'name' => 'New Category Name',
          'slug' => 'new-category-slug'
        )
    );

    // Insert New Category
    if(!term_exists('another-category')) {
        wp_insert_term(
            'Another Category',
            'category',
            array(
                'slug' => 'another-category'
            )
        );
    }
}

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'add_category');
```

This is tested and works.

Comment: I can also modify the default one of wordpress with this method?

Comment: Yes, I have updated my answer to give you a better example.